# how to recall random valuable from python

Tags: python, python-3.x

when I check the if condition the valuable num doesn't work. Only else work Why?
please help me I don't know what to do

```
from random import randrange


def ran():
    num=randrange(10,99)
    print("This is your ID",num)
    stid=input("Enter Your ID ")
    if stid==num:
        print("Welcome")
    else:
        print("Sorry Try Again")
ran()
```

Comment: You are comparing `int` with `str` (`input()` gives you an `str` object).

Comment: There are values and there are variables - there are no valuables.

Answer (score 0):

Input func accepts string only and explicitly need to convert to int. Your code is comparing string with num that is reason it is always getting into else part.

```
from random import randrange


def ran():
    num = randrange(10, 99)
    print("This is your ID", num)
    stid = int(input("Enter Your ID "))
    if stid == num:
        print("Welcome")
    else:
        print("Sorry Try Again")


ran()
```